# C# Random returning the same value

Tags: c#, random

I'm creating only one instance of random but even so the random number is the same.

```
       int x, y;
        Random random = new Random();
        // Loop through the images pixels to reset color. 
        for (x = 0; x < image1.Width; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < image1.Height; y++)
            {
                int randomNumber = random.Next(1, 2);
                if (randomNumber != 1) continue;
                Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
                image1.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean that the number is the same? Do you always receive the same value? Or do subsequent runs always give exactly the same result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting the same number (`1`) every time, because you're calling `Random.Next()` with `minValue = 1` and `maxValue = 2`:

[Random.Next Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx)

> *minValue*
>
> The **inclusive** lower bound of the random number returned.
>
> *maxValue*
>
> The **exclusive** upper bound of the random number returned. maxValue must
>   be greater than or equal to minValue.

**Calling `Random.Next(1, 2)` will always return `1`.**

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you'd like to change only 50% of your colors, you should probably do following:

```
for (x = 0; x < image1.Width; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y < image1.Height; y++)
    {
        if (random.Next() % 2 != 1) continue;
        Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x, y);
        Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
        image1.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats it I was lacking attention

Comment: Here I was just testing the randomness of random making a image where every pixel whoul be randomly black or white, like here http://www.random.org/bitmaps/